# Exporting predicates using :- module

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I know I can export predicates for a module by using the standard declaration:

```
:- module(my_test, [hello/1]).

hello(a).
hello(b).
```

But wanted to know is there another way I can export predicate hello in module my_test?  In the example below, what code would I need to fill in, to make my_export directive do this for me?

```
:- module(my_test, []).

hello(a).
hello(b).
:- my_export(hello/1).
```

I can't quite figure it out [import/export](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,%275.11%27,swi(%27/doc/Manual/altmoduleapi.html%27))) but those are the only real ways I can come up with.

Comment: Can you tell us the reason why you want this? You would most probably depend on some internal assumption that easily changes from release to release.

Comment: i'd like to write a system:term_expansion macro that changes the name and arity of a rule.  for instance a macro that turns hello(a) into my_hello(a, testcase123), then i'd like this exported for the current module.  ideally, system:term_expansion would invoke this 'export' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using

```
:- export(hello/1).
```

should do the trick.

Comment: export has to be called as a directive though?  do you think I can call export during system:term_expansion?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SWI, but as far as I know the module system is similar to the one used in ECLiPSe. For static predicates, you can use `export/1` as a directive. For dynamically generated predicates, you can call `export/1` from your code once the predicate has been generated.